# SQL Server - How do I Create/COMMIT Log Records during a Running Process that will potentially be ROLLEDBACK

Tags: sql-server, logging, commit, rollback

I am having much difficulty attempting to replicate Logging as I had done in Oracle using PRAGRMA AUTOMOUS_TRANSACTION which allows you to COMMIT records to a LOG table while NOT COMMITing any other DML operations.  I've been banging my head as to how more experienced SQL Server guys are LOGGING the Success or Errors of their Database Programs/Processes. Bascially how are experienced T-SQL guys logging in the middle of an active T-SQL program?  Another way to put it... I have a HUGE process that is NOT to be COMMITed until the entire process executes without Critical Errors but I still need to log ALL Errors and if it's a Critical Error then ROLLBACK entire process but I still need the Logs.

Using MERGE as Example demonstrating my inability to COMMIT some records but ROLLING back others ...

I have TWO named Transactions in the below script (1. sourceData, 2. mainProcess)... This is my first attempt at trying to accomplish this goal.  First the script INSERTs records using the 1st Transaction into a table without COMMIT.  Then in Transaction 2 in the MERGE block I am INSERTing records into the Destination table and the Log table and I COMMIT transaction 2 (mainProcess).

I then AM ROLLING BACK the 1st named Transaction (sourceData)..

The issue is... EVERYTHING is getting ROLLED Back even though I explicitly COMMITed the mainProcess Transaction.

```
GO
/* temp table to simulate Log Table */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LogTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #LogTable  
    (   Action                  VARCHAR(50),
        primaryID               INT,
        secondaryID             INT,
        CustomID                INT,
        Note                    VARCHAR(200),
        ConvDate                DATE
    ) --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LogTable;
;  /* SELECT * FROM #LogTable; TRUNCATE TABLE #LogTable; */

/* SELECT * FROM #ProductionSrcTable */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductionSrcTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #ProductionSrcTable(   primaryKey INT, contactName VARCHAR(200), sourceKey    INT  )
; --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProductionSrcTable; TRUNCATE TABLE #ProductionSrcTable;

/* SELECT * FROM #ProductionDestTable */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductionDestTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #ProductionDestTable(  primaryKey INT, contactName VARCHAR(200), secondaryKey INT  )
; --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProductionDestTable; TRUNCATE TABLE #ProductionDestTable;

GO

/* Insert some fake data into Source Table */
BEGIN TRAN sourceData

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #ProductionSrcTable
        SELECT 1001 AS primaryKey, 'Jason' AS contactName, 789105 AS sourceKey UNION ALL
        SELECT 1002 AS primaryKey, 'Jane'  AS contactName, 789185 AS sourceKey UNION ALL
        SELECT 1003 AS primaryKey, 'Sam'   AS contactName, 788181 AS sourceKey UNION ALL
        SELECT 1004 AS primaryKey, 'Susan' AS contactName, 681181 AS sourceKey
    ;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION sourceData
END CATCH

/* COMMIT below is purposely commented out in order to Test */
--COMMIT TRANSACTION sourceData

GO

BEGIN TRAN mainProcess

    DECLARE @insertedRecords    INT = 0,
            @CustomID           INT = 2,
            @Note               VARCHAR(200) = 'Test Temp DB Record Population via OUTPUT Clause',
            @ConvDate           DATE = getDate()
    ;

BEGIN TRY

    MERGE INTO #ProductionDestTable AS dest
    USING 

    (
        SELECT src.primaryKey, src.contactName, src.sourceKey FROM #ProductionSrcTable src

    ) AS src ON src.primaryKey = dest.primaryKey AND src.sourceKey = dest.secondaryKey

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN
        INSERT --INTO ProductionDestTable
        (   primaryKey, contactName, secondaryKey               )
        VALUES
        (   src.primaryKey, src.contactName, src.sourceKey      )


    /* Insert Output in Log Table  */
    OUTPUT $action, inserted.primaryKey, src.sourceKey, @CustomID, @Note, @ConvDate INTO #LogTable;


    ; /* END MERGE */

    /* Store the number of inserted Records into the insertedRecords variable */
    SET @insertedRecords = @@ROWCOUNT;

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION mainProcess
    END CATCH
;

--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION mainProcess
COMMIT TRANSACTION mainProcess

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION sourceData

PRINT 'Records Inserted:' + CAST(@insertedRecords AS VARCHAR);

/* END  */

--SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

Comment: The entire script in this post can safely be run in SQL Server as is.

Comment: use a @LogTable instead. Table variables are "transaction free"

Comment: @lptr Well... I only used Temp tables in my example... but in REALITY all of these Tables will persist and just be regular tables.  I simply posted SAMPLE code in order to get my point out there.

Comment: For something that is common practice and so easy to do in Oracle I'm finding it difficult to acknowledge that this isn't a needed feature in another database system.